# PHP Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap limit messages

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm using [Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.mail.read.html) to get mails from my account, the function works fine but.. How can I limit the results to show and prepare it for pagination?

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap(array('host'     => 'example.com',
                                         'user'     => 'test',
                                         'password' => 'test'));
foreach ($mail as $message) {
    echo "Mail from '{$message->from}': {$message->subject}\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pagination with the Zend_Mail_Storage classes is straight forward. They all implement iterator interfaces and can be combined with a LimitIterator for pagination. The only gotcha is that they start with 1 instead of 0, because that's what all mail interfaces do.

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap(array('host'     => localhost, 
                                         'user'     => 'test', 
                                         'password' => 'secret')); 

$mail = new LimitIterator($mail, 1, 50); 

print_r(iterator_to_array($mail));
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I'm looking for!